# Reformat dataframe into lists based on first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to reformat a dataframe so that each set of duplicate values in column one is replaced with a single header, which is then placed on its own row with the relevant data from columns two and three placed underneath it.

Here's what my current dataframe looks like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dups': ['Invoices-Invoices', 'Invoices-Invoices', 'Contracts-Invoices', 'Contracts-Contracts', 'Contracts-Contracts'],
    'FileOne': ['C:\text1.doc', 'C:\text2.doc', 'C:\text3.doc', 'C:\text4.doc', 'C:\text5.doc'],
    'FileTwo': ['C:\doc1.doc', 'C:\doc2.doc', 'C:\doc3.doc', 'C:\doc4.doc', 'C:\doc5.doc']
})
```

Here is what I would like my dataframe to look like:

[image]

I've tried `df.pivot()`, `df.melt()`, and `df.stack()`.  These approaches rearrange the data but not in the way that I am looking for.

Update thanks to Baron Legendre:

```
df['Files'] = df['FileOne'] + "-" + df['FileTwo']

df = df.melt(id_vars='Dups', value_vars=['Files']).groupby(['Dups', 'variable']).agg(list)

for header in df:
    for item in df['value']:
        print('header')
        for x in item:
            print(x)
```

Just trying to figure out how to print the headers, then move the whole thing to a csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original dataframe is already close to the desired state. All is left is to add the group subheaders on top of values:

```
groups = pd.Series(df['Dups'].unique())
header_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Dups': groups,
    'FileOne': groups,
    'FileTwo': pd.Series([], dtype=str)
}).fillna({'FileTwo': ''})

output_df = pd.concat([df.assign(level=1), header_df.assign(level=0)]).sort_values(['Dups', 'level']).reset_index(drop=True).iloc[:, -3:-1]
output_df   

    FileOne         FileTwo
0   Contracts-Contracts     
1   C:\text4.doc    C:\doc4.doc
2   C:\text5.doc    C:\doc5.doc
3   Contracts-Invoices  
4   C:\text3.doc    C:\doc3.doc
5   Invoices-Invoices   
6   C:\text1.doc    C:\doc1.doc
7   C:\text2.doc    C:\doc2.doc
```

**Update**: And just in case styling in your screenshot is also a must:

```
import numpy as np

output_df.style. \
    apply(lambda x: np.where(x.isin(groups), 'font-weight: bold', None), axis=1). \
    to_excel("test.xlsx", index=False, header=False)
```

.. will give you an Excel-file formatted like below:

[image: Styler to an Excel sheet]

Comment: Assign values in a column to sort, amazing.

Comment: This is very fast compared to the loop solution.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.melt(id_vars='Dups', value_vars=['FileOne', 'FileTwo']).groupby(['Dups', 'variable']).agg(list)
```

[image]

```
df.groupby('Dups').agg(list)
```

[image]

---

If you don't like list

```
og = df.groupby('Dups').agg(list)

df1 = og.FileOne.apply(pd.Series)
df2 = og.FileTwo.apply(pd.Series)

df1.columns = ['FileOne'] * len(df1.columns)
df2.columns = ['FileTwo'] * len(df2.columns)

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna('')
df3
```

[image]

If you want columns having suffix:

```
df1 = og.FileOne.apply(pd.Series)
df2 = og.FileTwo.apply(pd.Series)

df1.columns = ['FileOne_' + str(i) for i in df1.columns]
df2.columns = ['FileTwo_' + str(i) for i in df2.columns]

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1).fillna('')
df3
```

[image]

Another idea,

```
mt = df.melt(id_vars='Dups', value_vars=['FileOne', 'FileTwo'])
mt['ct'] = mt.groupby(['Dups','variable']).cumcount()
mt.pivot_table(index=['Dups','ct'], columns='variable', values='value', aggfunc=lambda x: x.unique()[0])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for working on this Baron.  For context, I'm giving this dataset to people who don't work with spreadsheets, so my goal is to make a very readable presentation of this information.  Your solution has given me lots of ideas, but it still isn't like the picture I provided involving headers, with the pairs of data listed below each header.

Comment: I concatenated `FileOne` and `FileTwo` into a column called `Files`, then applied your `df = df.melt(id_vars='Dups', value_vars=['Files']).groupby(['Dups', 'variable']).agg(list)` line.  It seems close.  I just need to make a new line for every comma.

Comment: Another idea had added, I add `cumcount()` to label how many Files are in the cross table.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({

    'Dups': ['Invoices-Invoices', 'Invoices-Invoices', 'Contracts-Invoices', 'Contracts-Contracts', 'Contracts-Contracts'],

    'FileOne': ['C:\text1.doc', 'C:\text2.doc', 'C:\text3.doc', 'C:\text4.doc', 'C:\text5.doc'],

    'FileTwo': ['C:\doc1.doc', 'C:\doc2.doc', 'C:\doc3.doc', 'C:\doc4.doc', 'C:\doc5.doc']

})

mylist = df['Dups'].tolist()
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))

# print(mylist)

df['Files'] = df['FileOne'] + "-" + df['FileTwo']

finalList = []
for x in mylist:
    finalList.append("")
    finalList.append(x)
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i, "Dups"] == x:
            finalList.append(df.loc[i, "Files"])
            
            
print(finalList)

df = pd.DataFrame(finalList)

df.to_csv("NamesOfDuplicates2.csv")
```